# Lost in django and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, django

Im' asked to debug a project but i never used django before, and i'm quite a roookie with jquery.

The problem i'm facing follows and leads to several questions :

- there are at least 2 calls to jquery: one in base.html in `[project]/src/templates` and the other call is in `[project]/templates/[project]/data_form.html`

In both files, i modified the call to be exactly the same (it wasn't before) and it looks like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/static/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

I also added my favorite tracker's instruction just after :

```
<script>
    alert('fonctionne toujours');
</script>
```

further in the page , there is a button that create a new form when clicked.

At this point, if i run the project, when you clic the button, it works and the form is loaded. And all my `alert()` calls are working.

But if i remove one of the lines

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/static/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

and i keep the other, the button doesn't work anymore.

The removed line can be the first or the second one, it leads to the same result: the button doesn't react anymore.

To be certain that the library is well loaded, i also added a `alert()` message inside `jquery.js`. 
At it's begining first, and then at its whole end.

Surprisingly, this `alert()` code never shown, with a single or with the two calls to jquery.

Moreover, if i read the source page (in firefox) and click the link to `jquery.js` , to read the loaded content, my `alert()` isn't in the source page.

Here are my questions :

- is there an explanation why the button doesn't work anymore when it miss 1 call of two and when those calls are the sames ?
- How comes that the modified `jquery.js` doesn't show the modified part , even after a restart of the server ?

As asked here is my template code :

/* data_form.html */
/* in my project */

```
<!-- 
next line is commented to be certain to point to the same jquery.js here and in base.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/static/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    alert('data-form jquery');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my_admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/calendar.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js' %}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formset").formset();
});
</script>
```

/* base.html */

```
<!--
next line is commented to be certain to point to the same jquery.js here and in data_form.html  
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script> 
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/static/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    alert('base jquery');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add your template code along with your javascript?

Comment: When running .manage.py collectstatic the static files are copied to folder specified in STATIC_ROOT setting. This may be the case that you have DEBUG=True i.e development mode and you have chnaged wrong copy of the jquery.js. Please search again if there are 2 copies of the file and have modified the worng copy

Comment: Okey. To avoid those problems, the two calls
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/static/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

are replaced with this call (in both files) :
    <script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 

I also replaced the 2 "alert()" calls with a nicer "console.log()" in my files and directly in jquery.js .

Every call to "console.log()" works and the source of my file reflects what i need :) My second question is than solved. Remains only the first one. should i create a single post for it ?